# Rails 3 eager load and include attributes from association in json or xml

Tags: ruby, xml, json, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

For my API, I need to eager load all clients, items for client and their prices and return them as JSON or XML.

```
Model Client
has_many items

Model Item
belongs to :client
has_many :prices

Model Price
belongs_to :item
```

I need to build a hierarchical result `@tree` using all attributes from all three associations staring with each Client -> each Item -> each Price to send back as JSON and XML response for API call.

so:

> ```
> @tree =  Client_1
>          --Item_1
>            --Price_1
>            --Price_2
>          --Item_2
>            --Price_3
>            --Price_4
>          Client_2
>          ... and so on
> ```

```
        respond_to do |format|
        format.xml {render :xml =>{@tree}}
        format.json {render :json =>{@tree}}
        end
```

UPDATE::

I have tried includes, joins, pre-load eager_load and everything else. All these only bring attributes from the top most Model, i.e. Client. They DO NOT load attributes from associations. I have even tried [Retrieve all association's attributes of an AR model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299139/retrieve-all-associations-attributes-of-an-ar-model). It somewhat does what I need but not all of it. It does not put the @tree in hierarchy I need. It creates it like

> ```
> @tree =  Client_1
>          --Item_1
>          --Item_2
>          --Price_1
>          --Price_2
>          --Price_3
>          --Price_4
> ```

which is NOT what I need.

Comment: What have you tried. Have you looked into `eager_load` or `include` as query methods? There are even ways to build this into the model so these are always eager loaded if that's your intention but without knowing that you have tried on your own I'd rather not just solve your problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

@tree = Client.includes(:items => [:prices]).all

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations